# Can I define (substitute for) the word 'albeit' as 'regardless'?

Tags: linking-verbs

We hear a song from our past and are transported back to a memory from long ago, **albeit** a good or a bad one

[link](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/albeit) to the sentence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**albeit** is synonymous with **although (it be)** not **though it may be**. You can use **whether it be** or **though it may be** instead of **albeit**.

**albeit** has a slightly musty smell, like an old book store.

> This is the most direct route to the town, albeit a dangerous one. Brigands are known to rob travelers at musket-point along it.

The most contemporary way of expressing your idea is probably **though it may be**.

Answer (score 0):

In this sentence, "albeit" is best translated as "although it might be."

> We hear a song from our past and are transported back to a memory from long ago, although the memory might be a good or a bad one

Comment: Thanks. Is 'regardless' COMPLETELY inappropriate? (e.g. regardless they are good or bad)

Comment: The word you're looking for here is ***whether** [good or bad]*.